Clicking on "See More" in Facebook WITHOUT mouse on Firefox or Chrome
I tried using Ctrl+F, input "See More", Esc, then Enter, but it does not work.
What other keyboard shortcut can I used to trigger "See More" in Facebook for long posts? An extension or 3ʳᵈ party user script will be even better!

Its not obvious what you are asking?

That flow works for me. "Does not work" is a bad way to describe things.
